# ¿como valido un dato en java?

Tags: java

Por ejemplo pido un dato entero y al introducir por ejemplo por teclado una letra, me diga que el dato introducido no es valido.

He puesto esto, pero no me funciona

```
while (teclado.hasNextInt()==false) 

    System.out.println("El caracter introducido no es valido");

    teclado.next();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sencillo, `nextInt()` solo puede recibir enteros, si le pasas una letra este lanzara una excepción. Puedes manejar esa excepción con `try catch` dentro de un ciclo `while`, el cual mientras se introduzcan valores no numéricos se siga ejecutando y cuando se introduzca un numero se detenga.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class Numero{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numero;
        boolean noEsNumero = true;

        System.out.println("Ingrese el numero");

        // El while evaluá la variable noEsNumero la cual es true por defecto,
        // a esta se le asigna el valor false si el valor ingresado por el 
        // usuario es un numero. Mientras el valor que ingrese el usuario 
        // no sea un numero, el while se ejecutara.
        while (noEsNumero) {

            try {

                // Recibe el valor ingresado por el usuario, si el valor ingresado
                // por el usuario no es un numero, el try se ejecutara hasta
                // esta linea y saltara al catch. Pero si es un numero, el try se
                // ejecutara completo y le asignara a la variable noEsNumero es valor
                // false, lo que detendrá el ciclo. 
                numero = teclado.nextInt();
                noEsNumero = false;

            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Error: no es un numero");
                System.out.println("Intentelo de nuevo");
            }

            // Esta linea es necesaria para el correcto funcionamiento de la entrada.
            // esta linea siempre debe ir después de utiliza el método nextInt(). 
            teclado.nextLine();

        }

        // Cierra el teclado
        teclado.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: No conocía el try ni el catch, pero ahora lo usaré

Comment: @marxal La respuesta soluciono tu problema?

Comment: @marxal si la respuesta te fue de ayuda recuerda dar las gracias de manera constructiva, como dando un **voto** a favor o marcando la respuesta como **aceptada**, tal como se explica en el **[recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)** del sitio.

Comment: La programación es un proceso largo, no se aprende de la noche a la mañana. Hay conceptos básicos que a mi me ha tomado mas de un año poder entenderlos. Lo que te recomiendo es que si no entiendes algo, saltalo y sigue adelante, después vuelve a estudiarlo y veras como lo entiendes. No hay que saber como funciona todo para utilizarlo, solo hay que saber lo suficiente como para hacerlo funcionar, después mas al paso y con el tiempo se va entendiendo su funcionamiento y mientras se conoce algo mejor se puede implementar.