# Reiniciar la aplicación Java al obtener una excepción

Tags: java

Buenas, para el código citado abajo, resulta que quiero que después de la excepción empiece de nuevo a pedir los datos, es decir, que se reinicie el try, ¿qué opciones tengo? He probado a hacer bucles con do-while y for, pero creo que no los formulo correctamente.

Gracias.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    /*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */

    /**
     *
     * @author Cristobal
     */
    public class Ejercicio4 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a, b = 0;

    try
    {


            System.out.println("Escribe el número del día de la semana");
            a = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Escribe el número del mes");
            b = sc.nextInt();

}

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Has introducido un valor incorrecto");

    }
}

}
```

El intento con un bucle que hice era algo como esto:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Cristobal
 */
public class Ejercicio4 {
    public static int a;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int b = 0;

    while (! sc.hasNextInt()) {

    try
    {


            System.out.println("Escribe el número del día de la semana");
            a = sc.nextInt();


            System.out.println("Escribe el número del mes");
            b = sc.nextInt();

}

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Has introducido un valor incorrecto");

    }

    }
}

}
```

También he intentado sin éxito lo siguiente:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Cristobal
 */
public class Ejercicio4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a, b;



    try
    {
        do {
            System.out.println("Escribe el número del día de la semana");
            a = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Escribe el número del mes");
            b = sc.nextInt();

    } while (! sc.hasNextInt());
    } 



    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Has introducido un valor incorrecto");

    }

    }

    }
```

Comment: Por favor comparte tus intentos.

Comment: Añade el código con el bucle que no termina de funcionarte, en realidad es tan sencillo como añadir un *flag* que indique si tienes que salir del bucle o no

Comment: Editado, pero no me sale bien esto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El funcionamiento de un `while` es sencillo. Mientras la condición del `while` sea verdadera, este se ejecutara, cuando esta sea falsa se detendrá. Sabiendo eso, implementar el while es sencillo.

Ahora bien, el `try` `catch` funciona de la siguiente manera. El `try` se ejecuta hasta la linea de codigo que falla. Cuando una linea de codigo falla dentro del `try`, este interrumpe su ejecucion y salta al `catch`, lo que impide que el `try` se ejecute por completo si se provoca un error (exepcion). El valor del condicional del `while` tienes que cambiarlo despues de la linea dentro del `try` que puede fallar. De esta manera el `while` se detendra si en el `try` no ocurren errores, de lo contrario se seguira ejecutando.

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
    int a, b = 0;

    // El valor del condicional del while es true por defecto.
    boolean esIncorrecto = true;

    while(esIncorrecto) {

        try { 

            System.out.println("Escribe el número del día de la semana"); 
            a = sc.nextInt(); 

            System.out.println("Escribe el número del mes"); 
            b = sc.nextInt(); 

            // Si no ocurren exepciones, modificas el valor del condicional del while a false para detener el ciclo.
            esIncorrecto = false;

        } catch (Exception e) { 
            System.out.println("Has introducido un valor incorrecto"); 
        } 

        // esta linea siempre debe ir despues de nextInt()
        sc.nextLine();
    }
}
```

En esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/108103/como-valido-un-dato-en-java) doy una [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/108103/como-valido-un-dato-en-java/108126#108126) similar a la dada aqui.

Comment: He intentado hacer esto que me escribes, pero se genera un bucle infinito de esta forma:

Has introducido un valor incorrecto
Escribe el número del día de la semana
Has introducido un valor incorrecto
Escribe el número del día de la semana
Has introducido un valor incorrecto
Escribe el número del día de la semana
Has introducido un valor incorrecto
Escribe el número del día de la semana
Has introducido un valor incorrecto
Escribe el número del día de la semana
Has introducido un valor incorrecto
Escribe el número del día de la semana

Comment: He editado mi pregunta, prueba de nuevo. Al final del while agregue una linea que evitara la ejecución del ciclo de manera infinita.

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a la línea mágica sc.nextLine(); que me has sugerido, he podido diseñar algo que se adapta más a mi pequeño conocimiento de Java, el uso de booleans es algo que debo aprender a manejar para este tipo de ejercicios, así que también me será de utilidad. Muchas gracias :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Cristobal
 */
public class Ejercicio4 {

    public static int a, b;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

do {

    try
    {
            System.out.println("Escribe un número entero");
            a = sc.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Escribe otro número entero");
            b = sc.nextInt();
    } 



    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Has introducido un valor incorrecto");
        sc.nextLine();
    }
    } while ((a == 0) || (b == 0));

    }
}
```