# Validar Datos Obtenidos por el usuario con do while

Tags: java, validación

Buenas tardes! Después de mirar y pedir opiniones he obtenido las dos maneras que se puede. Sólo funciona, si el **usuario inserta un número**. Resalto, si inserta **letra/caracter** *NO FUNCIONA*.

```
    short n;
    do {
        System.out.println("Escribir un número entre 11 i 90");
        n = ss.nextShort();
        if (n >= 10 && n <= 90) {
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Valor introducido incorrecto");
            System.out.println("Vuelva introducir nu número");
        }
    } while (true);
```

En este caso puedes personalizar decir al usuario si el número no está entre **10 i 90**, personalizar el mensaje de "retorno"(else), con "Valor introducido incorrecto".

> Nota: Utilizo "short" y no int, porque el usuario me pide un número de 16bits.

El siguiente es más "*corto*", pero no te deja personalizar el mensaje si es un **else**. Sólo te dice "Escribe 10 i 90", pero funciona.

```
  short n;
    do{
        Scanner ss = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Escribe 10 i 90");
        n = ss.nextShort();
        System.out.println("tu número es:" +n);

    }while (n < 10 || n >90);
```

Comment: Esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/108103/como-valido-un-dato-en-java/108126#108126) es muy similar a la tuya. En ella doy una respuesta que también soluciona tu problema.

Comment: @david No es lo mismo, editado mi pregunta, espero que eso pueda ver la diferencia  o recomendar a cambiar el concepto de mi pregunta por otra.

Answer (score 1):

Mi propuesta es la siguiente. Al introducir la cadena pedida por teclado, con la expresion regular [0-9] (valida para una cifra), comprueba si la cadena es valida o no. Si es valida, convierte la cadena a entero y le muestra por consola, por el contrario, muestra error y la variable que controla el while se asigna a `false`. Así, mientras `correcto` sea `false`, se repetira el do-while.

```
    Scanner sn= new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean correcto = false;

    do{

    System.out.println("Escribe un número");
    String num= sn.nextLine();

    if (num.matches("[0-9]")) {
        correcto=true;
        int numero = Integer.parseInt(num);
        System.out.println("El número introducido es " + numero);
    } else {
        correcto=false;
        System.out.println("Repite de nuevo");
    }

    }while(correcto==false);
```

Comment: Hola, en este caso no me funciona si inserto un número 20, supongo que se podría, si es así, me gustaría que lo comentes. Al final he modificado arriba las dos maneras que he podido

Comment: Hola, si, se puede modificar la expresión regular dentro del `matches()`.  Por ejemplo, `[0-9]{1,3}` permite introducir un numero con mínimo 1 cifra y máximo 3, por lo que si introduces 20 te lo mostraría correctamente. Espero haberte ayudado. @Bob